# Order Wordpress Loop by Custom Metabox Field REF: IP METABOX PLUGIN

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, meta-key

Using IP Metabox Plugin on Wordpress i have a Metabox called 'ipmb_metabox_4'

and the field 'price' is used within it.

IP Metabox (https://wordpress.org/plugins/ip-metaboxes/) uses the following code to call a Metabox/Custom Field Value.

```
<?php $values = ipmb_get_metabox_values('ipmb_metabox_4');
                                    foreach($values as $i => $value) {
        echo "{$value['price']}";
            }
        ?>
```

i wish to order the loop with price asc.

so far i have

```
query_posts(array(
'post_type'      => 'used',
'paged'          => $paged,
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'order'          => 'ASC',
'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
'meta_key'       => 'price',
                ));
```

But this doesn't work and i assume its because IP Metabox doesn't register the Custom Post Meta like wordpress normally does with Custom Meta Fields. Could anyone advise please?

SOLVED:

```
query_posts(array(
                        'post_type'      => 'used', // You can add a custom post type if you like
                        'paged'          => $paged,
                        'posts_per_page' => 4,
                        'meta_key'       => 'ipmb_metabox_4_price',
                        'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
                        'order'          => 'ASC',

                    ));
```

Thank your to the Author of IP Metabox for the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't works because your meta key was wrong. Since the metabox ID is `ipmb_metabox_4` and your field is `price`, the meta key should be `ipmb_metabox_4_price`. I'm sorry I didn't write any documentation about this, because I don't think people want to access to the meta key directly :)